# Why text yanked into the Isearch search string is always in lower case?

Tags: isearch

Emacs 26.1

I select the next text:

```
NO_PERMISSION_GRANTED_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_and_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

C-s , then paste text onto the search string.

Here result:

[image]

Why text is not in UPPER CASE? It's always in lower case?

Comment: Isearch does not use the minibuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why in minibuffer text is always in lower case?

It isn't.  This is just an isearch feature.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `search-upper-case`

> `C-s` , then paste text in minibuffer.

For clarity (maybe), in your example you're not pasting anything into the minibuffer.  The search prompt is being displayed in the *echo area* (which shares its *window* with the minibuffer), and you're not in the minibuffer when you paste.  So this feature of isearch doesn't actually affect the minibuffer at all.